# dynamic riccati equation (ode with matrix variable)

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, ode

Hello I have a problem solving the following dynamic riccati equation:

[image: riccati equation]

This is the code I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def deriv(sigma, t, A, B, Md):
    sigma = np.reshape(sigma, s)
    return (-np.matmul(A, sigma) - np.matmul(sigma, A.transpose()) + B - 2 * np.matmul(sigma, Md, sigma)).flatten()

n = 100
alpha = 5
beta = 5

G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(n=n, m=2, seed=10374196, initial_graph=None)
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G).toarray()  # Convert to dense matrix
B = alpha * np.identity(n)
Md = np.identity(n)
Md[1, 1] = beta
s = (n, n)
sigma0 = np.ones(n**2)
t = np.linspace(0, 100, 101)

sol = odeint(deriv, sigma0, t, args=(A, B, Md)) 
sol = np.reshape(sol, (len(t),) + s)  
Y = np.linalg.eigvals(sol[-1])  
Y.sort()
X = [i for i in range(n)]
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.xlabel("eigenvalue rank")
plt.ylabel("eigenvalue")
plt.show()
```

I am testing the stationary solution and I am getting a zero matrix even though I know it shouldn't be possible for that to happen since these are the eigenvalues for the expected solution stationary solution of the riccati equation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADw8a.png)
Does anyone know where I've made a mistake ?

Comment: Do you get a warning about the solution exploding (step size reducing to effectively zero)? After such an error, the allocated but not used regions of the output are either zero or random.

Answer (score 1):

Copying and running your exact code, I was unable to get a solution due to overflow errors. I changed your code to use the more modern [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) ODE solver and changed your `deriv` function to use some numpy shorthand. With those changes, I got a non-zero solution matrix for all times. I'm not sure if your issues are related to using `odeint` (the outdated scipy ODE solver) or something else.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")


def deriv(t, sigma, A, B, Md):
    sigma = np.reshape(sigma, s)
    return (-A@sigma - sigma@A.T + B - 2*sigma@Md@sigma).ravel()


n = 100
alpha = 5
beta = 5

G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(n=n, m=2, seed=10374196, initial_graph=None)
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G).toarray()
B = alpha * np.identity(n)
Md = np.identity(n)
Md[1, 1] = beta
s = (n, n)
sigma0 = np.ones(n**2)
t = np.linspace(0, 100, 101)

sol = solve_ivp(deriv, [t.min(), t.max()], sigma0, t_eval=t, args=(A, B, Md,))
sigma = sol.y.T.reshape(len(t), n, n)
```

Comment: `odeint` is still faster and slightly simpler to use. Is using `solve_ivp` also without problem using `method='LSODA'`? The point being, using the tolerance defaults blindly can be hightly inappropriate, setting sensible tolerances could also lead to `odeint` integrating to the end.

Comment: What about `odeint` is simpler than `solve_ivp`? I've found that it can essentially work as a drop-in replacement, barring the change of function signature (unless using `tfirst` for `odeint`) and supplying the time range rather than the time evaluation points (which is optional for `solve_ivp`). And yes, `solve_ivp` worked on this problem with the `LSODA` method, but it was slower than the default `RK45` solver.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Don't take my response as an argument, I am interested in learning more and understanding the distinction between the function and why one might be better (at least in some cases) than the other. From looking at the documentation, `odeint` appears to be a dedicated `LSODA` solver rather than the more general `solve_ivp` function.

Comment: If your aim is just to convert a time series into a value series for a plot or as part of the objective function for some fitting task, then odeint requires less unpacking than solve_ivp. That's nothing big, only a slight advantage. // I might have understood that wrong, but one point of motivation of solve_ivp was to implement the solvers fully in python, so that they also work with complex or multi-precision data types (?). This would automatically be slower than the Fortran-Code in odepack. // Comments are sometimes actually used for comments. I should care to formulate less combative.

Comment: @DestroctiveBlade If this worked then you can accept this as the answer.